# How do I stop getting more than one request for an input?

Tags: java, input

I'm new to this website. Every time I run this program I made in eclipse, I get more than one request for an input. It's a neat little game I think. Here is the code.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Fight extends Attacker {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner defend = new Scanner(System.in);
    String response;
    int blocks = 0, possibleblocks = 0;
    System.out.println("Commence mental training. Enter \"Done.\" to finish. Ready?");
    response = defend.nextLine();
    while (response.equals(response) != response.equals("Done.")) {
      System.out.println(Hit());
      if (Hit() == "Left jab.") {
        response = defend.nextLine();
        if (response.contains("Right block.")) {
          blocks++;
        } else {
          System.out.println("Wrong.");
        }
      } else if (Hit() == "Right jab.") {
        response = defend.nextLine();
        if (response.contains("Left block.")) {
          blocks++;
        } else {
          System.out.println("Wrong.");
        }
      } else if (Hit() == "Left side punch.") {
        response = defend.nextLine();
        if (response.contains("Right side block.")) {
          blocks++;
        } else {
          System.out.println("Wrong.");
        }
      } else if (Hit() == "Right side punch.") {
        response = defend.nextLine();
        if (response.contains("Left side block.")) {
          blocks++;
        } else {
          System.out.println("Wrong.");
        }
      } else if (Hit() == "Left uppercut.") {
        response = defend.nextLine();
        if (response.contains("Step back.")) {
          blocks++;
        } else {
          System.out.println("Wrong. You should have stepped back.");
        }
      } else if (Hit() == "Right uppercut.") {
        response = defend.nextLine();
        if (response.contains("Step back.")) {
          blocks++;
        } else {
          System.out.println("Wrong. You should have stepped back.");
        }
      } else if (Hit() == "Lower right jab.") {
        response = defend.nextLine();
        if (response.contains("Step back.")) {
          blocks++;
        } else {
          System.out.println("Wrong. You should have stepped back.");
        }
      }
      possibleblocks++;
    }
    possibleblocks -= 1;
    double accuracy = ((double) blocks / (double) possibleblocks) * 100;
    System.out.println(blocks + " / " + possibleblocks);
    System.out.println("Your total accuracy is " + accuracy + "%.");
    defend.close();
  }
}
```

So, this is all in Java. In a gist, it gets an attack kind from the method you'll see next, prints it out, takes in input, checks to see if the input contains the correct blocking type, and calculates accuracy on how well you've blocked over how many times you could've blocked. The following is the class and method that gives the randomizer for the attacking type.

```
public class Attacker {
  public static String Hit() {
    int hit = 0 + (int) (Math.random() * 7);
    if (hit == 0) {
      return ("Left jab.");
    } else if (hit == 1) {
      return ("Right jab.");
    } else if (hit == 2) {
      return ("Left side punch.");
    } else if (hit == 3) {
      return ("Right side punch.");
    } else if (hit == 4) {
      return ("Left uppercut.");
    } else if (hit == 5) {
      return ("Right uppercut.");
    } else if (hit == 6) {
      return ("Lower right jab.");
    } else {
      return ("On the defensive.");
    }
  }
}
```

That creates a randomizer and creates the attack kinds. How can I make it so that it doesn't print out multiple attack types at the same time which then clogs up everything? Thank you.

Comment: You should learn to indent your code. It makes it easier for everybody trying to read it (that includes you).

Comment: You keep on calling `Hit()` in the conditions - every time you call it, it will pick a different number. Assign it to a variable: `int hit = Hit();`, and then use `hit` in your conditions instead of calling `Hit()` again.

Comment: Also: what do you think `response.equals(response) != response.equals("Done.")` does?

Comment: Sorry there. I'm new to this site. Learning the ways. The `response.equals(response) != response.equals("Done.");` is the condition for the while loop. Every time (and before) the loop runs, the program will take input (response). The loop runs as long as the input is not "Done."

Comment: Hey hey hey! Just realized my mistakes after taking in your second comment. Rather than creating an integer, I created `String Doosh = Hit();` in the while-loop that would take the place of `Hit()` in the conditions. Then from there, I replaced the conditions in the if-loops with `Doosh.equals("[insert attack type]")`. That fixed all of my problems. Thank you so much, Andy Turner!